# Does difficulty scale with multiple players

Tags: hammerwatch

Does the difficulty (number of monster, monster/boss HP, ect..) scale at all with the number of players?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The enemy speed, damage and health increase when in multilayer. The most noticeable change from my experience is the increase in boss health.

[From a steam discussion where one of the developers commented:](http://steamcommunity.com/app/239070/discussions/0/#p2])

> hipshot  [developer] Jun 21 @ 7:07am
>
> More players changes how fast enemies spawn, the damage and how much
>   health they have.
>
> ...

The post goes on and includes some more information about exact in game values, but there is no clear explanation on how the values relate to the real-time gameplay. (I speculate that the values with the 'Incr' and 'Decr' suffixes are the change that is applied to the base when each new player joins the game)